# how i can open htmls file as utf-8 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

i'm trying to open files as utf-8 in python.
i have list in htmls path, and my code for create the list work:

```
def get_all_htmls(directory_path):
    return glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory_path,'*.html'))

directory_path=r'C:\Users\astar\Project\Articles\Articles'
links = []
for html_path in get_all_htmls(directory_path):
    links.append(html_path)
```

but,now in this code :

```
for link in links:
    f=codecs.open(r'link','r','utf-8')
    document= BeautifulSoup(f)
```

no working for all htmls,what i can do?

Comment: Python 3 strings are Unicode and the default for `open` is already UTF-8. You don't need to do anything to read UTF8 files. If you have issues it means the files are *not* UTF8

Answer (score 1):

if it is working for some, but not all your files, this means that some of them are correctly encoded in utf-8, while others are probably encoded in some other encoding, (such as "ISO-8859-8", for Hebrew).
You don't say what is going wrong, which makes it hard to give you an exact answer in code, but if you are getting an `UnicodeDecodeError` exception on that call, you can make a loop that will try all suitable encodings until one succeeds:

```
for link in links:
    for encoding in ("utf-8", "iso-8859-8", "latin-1"):
        try:
            f=codecs.open(link,'r','utf-8')
            document= BeautifulSoup(f)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print(f"{encoding} failed for {link}, trying next encoding")
        else:
            print(f"Successfully read {link} as an {encoding} file") 
            break
    else: # for-level else, entered if no "break" statement was executed, 
          #and therefore, if no codec worked (although latin-1, in special, will always succeed)
         print(f"could not correctly read {link} with any of the avaliable encodings. skipping file")
         continue
```